# How to create duplicate resource in AWS using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to use terraform to crate aws resource say SQS in AWS. I have one SQS manually created trough AWS console. Now I am thinking import SQS through

> terrafom import
>   It will create .tfstate file. Can I use this file create resource config file .tf? So that either I can create similar sqs just with name change without repeating manual effort? Also I want to use .tf file to create same resource in other environment e.g. Prod

Answer (score 0):

No. You can certainly use terraform to create multiple (almost) identical resources, but you can't use it to generate your .tf file(s) for you.

For your situation, what you want to do is to write the configuration that you want for your SQS's in a .tf file, then use terraform to create them. Don't create them through the console. You can create multiple instances of a single resource definition by using [loops](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) or just the [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) meta-argument.

Answer (score 0):

you can build a module that receives instance ARN(for example) and uses terraforms Data for getting the resource configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).